# How to split rows to a fixed size and apply grep on each row or sublists

Tags: r

is there a way to split a data frame row to a fixed size and apply `grep` on each row?

I found only this function, but it returns a list with many sublist.

```
split(x, (0:nrow(x) %/% 300))
```

If there is no way, how can I apply the function `grep` on every sublist?

EDIT:

Small reproducible example:

```
a=c("cagtcccaaccataacagaagctggcctcctgaagcttacagtcaaaaac")
b=c("aatgattaaacatccatgcttatgaattccactgcagcctgctataactg")
c=c("taacaacatttaataatgaaagtaaatctgctacccccattatattttgc")

k=rbind(a,b,c)
```

Comment: To apply a function, e.g. `grep`, to every element of a list, you could use for example `lapply`. Could you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @beginneR 

I made an edit. Grep for `a` in each sublist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your small example in the question, I think it might not be very well suited since it doesn't really produce a list whereas `split` would produce a list. So I slightly change you example here:

```
a=c("cagtcccaaccataacagaagctggcctcctgaagcttacagtcaaaaac")
b=c("aatgattaaacatccatgcttatgaattccactgcagcctgctataactg")
c=c("taacaacatttaataatgaaagtaaatctgctacccccattatattttgc")

lst <- list(a,b,c)
lst
#[[1]]
#[1] "cagtcccaaccataacagaagctggcctcctgaagcttacagtcaaaaac"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "aatgattaaacatccatgcttatgaattccactgcagcctgctataactg"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "taacaacatttaataatgaaagtaaatctgctacccccattatattttgc"
```

Now, to apply `grep` to each element, you can do:

```
lapply(lst, function(vec) grep("a", vec))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1
```

This doesn't really look like it makes a lot of sense, but you get the idea of how to use `lapply` to apply `grep` to each element of a list (hopefully). Of course you could further modify the `grep` or whatever function you want to apply.

#### Edit

Maybe this is what you mean by "grep every a for each list"?

```
lapply(lst, function(vec){
  x <- gregexpr("a+", vec, perl = TRUE)
  res <- regmatches(vec, x)
  res
}) 

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "a"     "aa"    "a"     "aa"    "a"     "aa"    "aa"    "a"     "a"     "aaaaa"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "aa"  "a"   "aaa" "a"   "a"   "a"   "aa"  "a"   "a"   "a"   "aa" 
#
#
#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] "aa"  "aa"  "a"   "aa"  "aa"  "aaa" "aaa" "a"   "a"   "a"   "a"
```

#### Edit 2

```
lapply(lst, function(vec){
   x <- gregexpr("a+", vec, perl = TRUE)
   res <- sum(attr(x[[1]], "match.length"))
   res
})
#[[1]]
#[1] 18
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 16
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 19
```

Comment: Is there way to grep every `a` for each sublist? So I have a sum of each `a` in every list.

Comment: You mean you want to return all the `a`s of each list element in a vector?

Comment: Yeah, and have a see how many values are there in each sublist.

Comment: Would you count, for the first sublist, 10 or 18 hits?

Comment: 18 hits for the fist sublist.

Comment: Welcome, @Trik23. I'm not sure if that is the best / standard way of achieving this result. There might be some other, more efficient way.